# How to check if permutations have same parity?

Tags: python, list, permutation, parity

I am looking for a way to check if 2 **permutations** (represented by lists) are of the **same [parity](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parity_of_a_permutation)**. Note that I am not interested if they are *even* or *odd* parity, just the equality.

I am new to Python and my naive solution is given below as a reply. I am looking forward to Python gurus showing me some cool tricks to achieve the same in lesser, more elegant Python code.

Comment: Is a permutation a lists of disjoint cycles? A list of transposition pairs? A list of `(s, σ(s))` pairs (where σ is the permutation to be represented)?

Comment: Outis: I guess it can be both.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

A minor variant of the previous answer - copy perm1, and save array lookups.

```
def arePermsEqualParity(perm0, perm1):
    """Check if 2 permutations are of equal parity.

    Assume that both permutation lists are of equal length
    and have the same elements. No need to check for these
    conditions.
    """
    perm1 = perm1[:] ## copy this list so we don't mutate the original

    transCount = 0
    for loc in range(len(perm0) - 1):                         # Do (len - 1) transpositions
        p0 = perm0[loc]
        p1 = perm1[loc]
        if p0 != p1:
            sloc = perm1[loc:].index(p0)+loc          # Find position in perm1
            perm1[loc], perm1[sloc] = p0, p1          # Swap in perm1
            transCount += 1

    # Even number of transpositions means equal parity
    if (transCount % 2) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Answer (score 8):

If we combine both permutations, the result will have even parity when each permutation has the same parity, and odd parity if they have different parity. So if we solve the **parity problem** it's trivial to compare two different permutations.

**Parity** can be determined as follows: pick an arbitrary element, find the position that the permutation moves this to, repeat until you get back to the one you started with. You have now found a cycle: the permutation rotates all these elements round by one position. You need one swap less than the number of elements in the cycle to undo it. Now pick another element you haven't dealt with yet and repeat until you've seen every element. Observe that in total you needed one swap per element minus one swap per cycle.

Time complexity is O(N) in the size of the permutation. Note that although we have a loop within a loop, the inner loop can only ever iterate once for any element in the permutation.

```
def parity(permutation):
    permutation = list(permutation)
    length = len(permutation)
    elements_seen = [False] * length
    cycles = 0
    for index, already_seen in enumerate(elements_seen):
        if already_seen:
            continue
        cycles += 1
        current = index
        while not elements_seen[current]:
            elements_seen[current] = True
            current = permutation[current]
    return (length-cycles) % 2 == 0

def arePermsEqualParity(perm0, perm1):
    perm0 = list(perm0)
    return parity([perm0[i] for i in perm1])
```

Also, just for fun, here's a much less efficient but much shorter implementation of the parity function based on the definition in Wikipedia (returning True for even and False for odd):

```
def parity(p):
    return sum(
        1 for (x,px) in enumerate(p)
          for (y,py) in enumerate(p)
          if x<y and px>py
        )%2==0
```

Comment: `[p0[p1[i]] for i in xrange(len(p0))]` -> `[p0[i] for i in p1]`?

Comment: Hehe, it's so obvious now you point it out! I'll edit those in.

Comment: Many thanks for pointing out this alternate approach! It becomes all the more optimal (and useful) for a scenario where perm0 remains constant and is compared with a lot of perm1 lists.

Comment: In this solution, the input permutation is a list of what? Pairs of disjoint cycles for example?

Answer (score 6):

Here is my tweak of your code

- Use list() to copy perm1 - this means you can pass tuples, etc into the function, making it more generic
- Use enumerate() in the for loop instead of len(..) and array lookups for neater code
- Make a perm1_map and keep it up to date to stop an expensive O(N) search on perm1, and an expensive list slice
- return the boolean directly rather than the if ... return True else return False

Here is it

```
def arePermsEqualParity(perm0, perm1):
    """Check if 2 permutations are of equal parity.

    Assume that both permutation lists are of equal length
    and have the same elements. No need to check for these
    conditions.
    """
    perm1 = list(perm1) ## copy this into a list so we don't mutate the original
    perm1_map = dict((v, i) for i,v in enumerate(perm1))
    transCount = 0
    for loc, p0 in enumerate(perm0):
        p1 = perm1[loc]
        if p0 != p1:
            sloc = perm1_map[p0]                       # Find position in perm1
            perm1[loc], perm1[sloc] = p0, p1           # Swap in perm1
            perm1_map[p0], perm1_map[p1] = sloc, loc   # Swap the map
            transCount += 1
    # Even number of transpositions means equal parity
    return (transCount % 2) == 0
```

Answer (score 4):

My naive solution:

```
def arePermsEqualParity(perm0, perm1):
    """Check if 2 permutations are of equal parity.

    Assume that both permutation lists are of equal length
    and have the same elements. No need to check for these
    conditions.
    """

    transCount = 0
    for loc in range(len(perm0) - 1):                         # Do (len - 1) transpositions
        if perm0[loc] != perm1[loc]:
            sloc = perm1.index(perm0[loc])                    # Find position in perm1
            perm1[loc], perm1[sloc] = perm1[sloc], perm1[loc] # Swap in perm1
            transCount += 1

    # Even number of transpositions means equal parity
    if (transCount % 2) == 0:
        return True
    else:
        return False
```

Comment: The only improvement I can see is that the search perm1.index(perm0[loc]) only actually needs to check perm1 after loc - not sure how to express that efficiently in python.

Comment: I suppose we might want to copy perm1 so that the operation doesn't mutate the argument perm1?

Comment: Douglas: You are right about making a copy of perm1. I was not even aware that lists are passed by reference to functions (and thus modifiable within)!

Answer (score 3):

Here's slightly refactored [Weeble's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1503072/how-to-check-if-permutations-have-equal-parity/1504565#1504565):

```
def arePermsEqualParity(perm0, perm1):
    """Whether permutations are of equal parity."""
    return parity(combine(perm0, perm1))

def combine(perm0, perm1):
    """Combine two permutations into one."""
    return map(perm0.__getitem__, perm1)

def parity(permutation):
    """Return even parity for the `permutation`."""
    return (len(permutation) - ncycles(permutation)) % 2 == 0

def ncycles(permutation):
    """Return number of cycles in the `permutation`."""
    ncycles = 0
    seen = [False] * len(permutation)
    for i, already_seen in enumerate(seen):
        if not already_seen:
            ncycles += 1
            # mark indices that belongs to the cycle
            j = i 
            while not seen[j]: 
                seen[j] = True
                j = permutation[j]
    return ncycles
```

Answer (score 2):

The solution with the dictionary is bugged. 
This is the debug version:

```
def arePermsEqualParity(perm0, perm1):
    """Check if 2 permutations are of equal parity.

    Assume that both permutation lists are of equal length
    and have the same elements. No need to check for these
    conditions.
    """
    perm1 = list(perm1) ## copy this into a list so we don't mutate the original
    perm1_map = dict((v, i) for i,v in enumerate(perm1))
    transCount = 0
    for loc, p0 in enumerate(perm0):
        p1 = perm1[loc]
        if p0 != p1:
            sloc = perm1_map[p0]                       # Find position in perm1
            perm1[loc], perm1[sloc] = p0, p1           # Swap in perm1
            perm1_map[p0], perm1_map[p1] = loc, sloc   # Swap the map
            transCount += 1
    # Even number of transpositions means equal parity
    return (transCount % 2) == 0
```

The only differences is that the swap in the dictionary was not made correctly.

Answer (score 0):

My intuition tells me that, just counting the differences between the two permutations will give you one more than the number of swaps need to get from one to the other.  This in turn will give you the parity.

This means that you don't need to do the swaps in your code at all.

For example:

```
ABCD, BDCA.
```

There are three differences, hence two swaps are needed to permute one into the other, hence you have even parity.

Another:

```
ABCD, CDBA.
```

There are four differences, hence three swaps, hence odd parity.

Comment: BADC - 4 differences - only 2 swaps needed.

Comment: Counterexample:
 ABCD, BADC.
There are four differences, but only two swaps. (Swap AB, swap CD.) I believe the parity depends on the number of cycles.

Comment: Oops, looks like I was a bit late with that!

Comment: And that's why intuition sucks. Let reason prevail!

Answer (score 0):

```
def equalparity(p,q):
    return sum([p[q[i]] > p[q[j]] for i in range(len(p)) for j in range(i)]) % 2 == 0
```